# Javascript array goes undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I have a javascript function that assigns values to an array:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray =  myFunction();
next Statement;
```

When I get to next Statement, the array has gone undefined however if I comment out

```
myArray = myFunction();
```

the array is still defined at next Statement.

Please can someone explain what is going on.

Comment: Are you trolling or something? What do you expect `myArray` to be after assigning it to a function's return value?

Comment: Well, what is inside the body of the "myFunction"-function ? It seems like it is not returning a value.

Comment: myFunction is like this:

    function myFunction(row) {
      myArray[row] = [anotherArray];
    };

Comment: OK I got it now.  I just needed to code myFunction(); without assigning it to anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = [];
```

You declare `myArray` and assign a new, empty array object to it.

```
myArray =  myFunction();
```

You assign the return value of a call to `myFunction` to `myArray`.

This overwrites the previous value.

You haven't shown us the code for `myFunction`, but presumably it returns `undefined` (either because it has a `return` statement with an undefined value, or it has no `return` statement at all.

There are no longer any references to the array originally created on line 1, so the array gets garbage collected.

---

> I have a javascript function that assigns values to an array

If you want to assign a value *to* the array, then you need to either specify the index of the array to which you want to assign the value:

```
myArray[0] = myFunction();
```

or use something like [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add it to the end.

```
myArray.push(myFunction());
```

You will probably want to make `myFunction` return something other than `undefined` though.

---

It is possible that your implementation of `myFunction` modifies the array directly, e.g…

```
function myFunction () {
    myArray.push(1);
}
```

… in which case your original code would work if you just removed the part where the return value was assigned to the variable previously referencing the array:

```
/* myArray = */ myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not returning any value inside the function, so by default it will returns nothing hence making your array undefined.

If you want to assign a complete array to myArray, return that array in your function.

or if you just want to add elements to myArray inside your function, use push() method like e.g. myArray.push(element);